# JSON parse error on line 5: expecting 'STRING', ' , got "undefined'

Tags: json

I keep getting an error on line 5  and am not sure why, my quotation marks seem good.

```
{
    "tickets": [
        { 
            "id": "{{ticket.id}}",
            "additional_tags": [{% for cc in ticket.ccs %}"{{ cc.email }}"{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: `[{%` doesn't look like JSON to me. Are you sure this isn't used by some other tool? In that case you should probably quote the entire line, `"[{%...`".

Comment: I see what you meant I rectified it and it worked, thanks!